# How to save the output of an interactive command-line program in a Unix-like shell?

Tags: c, shell, unix, command-line, redirect

I am coding in C and running the programs in a Linux terminal. I want to save the output of the program in a .txt file. I usually do this by executing `./a.out>filename.txt`

But I have written an interactive program in which I have to enter a number to initiate the program. In that case how do I do it?

Thanks a lot and your valuable suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the requirement to enter a number from the terminal to a command line parameter.

```
./a.out 42 > filename.txt
```

Or, easier, accept the input from a redirected input

```
echo 42 | ./a.out > filename.txt
./a.out < input.txt > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
./a.out | tee filename.txt
```

[Tee man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee)

Comment: This doesn't allow access to stdin for inputting the args

Comment: actually ur suggestion works when the code is not interactive but when it requires some input from our side..it dsnt word...anyways thnx for your reply

Comment: thnx finally it worked coz of ur suggestion actually i made mistake while typing innitially..thanx buddy once again

Answer (score 6):

You can use `script` to capture all output to a file.

[$ man script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enter the number you wish to pass the to the program in an file called 'input.txt'. If you want to re-direct the output to 'output.txt', then type at the command-line:

```
./a.out  <  input.txt  >  output.txt
```