# Get number of Lines in Console

Tags: c++

I am creating a program in C++ that prints many (hundreds) of lines to the console. I want to know how many lines there are in the console output. Also, a solution where keeping track of every `endl` that I've `cout`ed would be tedious since there are many, many different places where this is done.

Basically, if I had the following code:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {

    cout << "hi" << endl << endl;

}
```

Then then I want a function that will tell me that the console is 2000 lines long.

Comment: Consider directing your output to a stream other than `std::cout`. Then, you can redirect that stream to wherever you please, after updating information such as line count.

Comment: At this point, changing all of the `std::cout`s would be tedious since there are so many of them. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Here's another idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174174/how-to-save-the-output-of-an-interactive-command-line-program-in-a-unix-like-she

Comment: You can run a search replace and keep (gasp) a global stream instance if you want quick and dirty.

Comment: You can change all the `cout`s in literally 5 seconds in even the most lightweight of IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but you could use another index.

```
int numLines = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    ++numLines;
}
// ...
// call this when the program finishes
std::cout << "Number of lines: " << numLines << std::endl;
```

Edit: would also work for multiple endl commands, you'd just need to remember to increment your index once for each call.